# What's the use of this machine (energy symbol) and when/how can I use it?

Tags: void-bastards

I found the following machine:

[image: bottom part]

But there is no explanation what it does and how to use it.

Here is a picture of the top panel:

[image: top panel]

How do I use it and what's for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a ship where everything was RED glowing and all doors were opened, could not open drawers and gunpoint deactivated. That's because the ship was without power. To turn them on you have to use that machine.

Answer (score 0):

There are various factors for a ship to have its energy disabled :

- Some ships will have its energy deactivated when you enter it.
- Some ships will have its energy deactivated at random times when you are in it.

**These interfaces allow you to enable energy.**

When energy is disabled :

- Doors are all opened
- You can't interact with doors, drawers and any other interface than energy activator
- All turrets are disabled (it's a good time to destroy those without risks)
- You can't leave the ship

Comment: I suppose this falls under "can't interact with doors", but it may be worth pointing out that a lack of power also means you cannot leave the ship.